# format text in flutter web after pasting text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a text field in chat application where I paste a text with line breaks and spaces in between which is properly formatted but after pasting it on the text field and submitting it all the format is gone and all I get is a just paragraph, I am using a text widget to display the message what am I doing wrong.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/rich_input , check this plugin may it might help

Answer (score 0):

haan. i will try to help u out.
create a variable of your text and call that in ur textfield

```
var text= 'hello stackoverflow';
printf(text);
```

use setstate to save that variable by textfield and print that by calling that variable